Extracting daybook / transaction data with ledger parent from Tally via ODBC
I am able to successfully extracted the All vouchers data by 1st creating below TDL
[Collection: RTSAllVouchers]
Type: Voucher
IsODBCTable: Yes
Fetch : *, AllLedgerEntries.*, LedgerEntries.*
And afterwards by running below SELECT statement
Select $Date,$Reference,$VouchertypeName,$PartyLedgerName,$$CollectionField:$Amount:1:LedgerEntries from RTSAllVouchers where $$IsSales:$VoucherTypeName 
However, I also need to extract LEDGER PARENT, Primary Group,Subgroup & Stock Item Name with additional units object.
Please provide detailed solution.

Experts please guide

you can add following code to get the values:
[#object: InventoryEntry]
itemParent : $parent:stockItem:$stockItemName
in you collection
fetch: AllInventoryEntries.itemParent
